# perl remove data from array with field separator

Tags: arrays, perl, variables

I have following perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my (@failhost);
my %currblocked;
my %addblocked;
my $action;

open (MYINPUTFILE, "/var/log/asterisk/messages") or die "\n", $!, "Does log file file exist\?\n\n";

while (<MYINPUTFILE>) {
    my ($line) = $_;
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ m/\' failed for \'(.*?)\' - No matching peer found/) {
        push(@failhost,$1);
    }
    if ($line =~ m/\' failed for \'(.*?)\' . Wrong password/) {
        push(@failhost,$1);
        print $1 . "\n";
    }
}
exit 0;
```

This produces following results.

```
212.83.134.244:5065
212.83.134.244:5063
212.83.134.244:5092
212.83.134.244:5109
212.83.134.244:5080
212.83.134.244:5110
212.83.134.244:5096
212.83.134.244:5093
212.83.134.244:5089
212.83.134.244:5073
212.83.134.244:5101
212.83.134.244:5072
212.83.134.244:5092
212.83.134.244:5094
212.83.134.244:5076
212.83.134.244:5080
212.83.134.244:5081
212.83.134.244:5094
212.83.134.244:5077
212.83.134.244:5096
212.83.134.244:5069
212.83.134.244:5097
212.83.134.244:5101
```

I want to remove all the ports numbers including ":", just want to retain the IP address.

Desired result would be like this

```
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
212.83.134.244
```

I would appreciate if some one can guide me, or show me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify second if like this

```
if ($line =~ m/\' failed for \'([^:]*):\d+\' . Wrong password/) {
```

Comment: You are a star, thank you. It works absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing $1, store it in a variable, remove the port details, and print it:

```
my $ip = $1;
$ip =~ s/:.*//;
print $ip, "\n";
```

Comment: no it does not work, I get following error.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in print at ./block_asterisk.pl line 21, <MYINPUTFILE> line 159410

Comment: @user2107349: Print $ip, not $1.